# PDFBox ERROR Could not load font file

Tags: linux, fonts, pdfbox

I am unsure if it is a PDFBox issue. But mentioning it might help understand my issue.

So I have been getting a lot of these warnings coming from PDFBox:

```
WARN  No Unicode mapping for a37 (37) in font TCBLZV+LCIRCLE10
```

This is one out of 100s.

So I decided to add the LCRICLE10 font and other fonts that are mentioned in the warning list.

Here are the fonts I downloaded:

- LCRICLE10: https://en.m.fontke.com/font/11103279/download/
- https://ctan.org/pkg/cm-super
- https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/cm/ps-type1/bakoma/
- CMEX: https://github.com/jondot/dotfiles/tree/master/.fonts

Here is the PDFBox error I am getting:

```
5517 ERROR Could not load font file: /home/$USER/.fonts/bakoma/pfb/eurb9.pfb
5518 java.io.IOException: Found Token[kind=NAME, text=dup] but expected INTEGER
5519    at org.apache.fontbox.type1.Type1Parser.read(Type1Parser.java:812)
5520    at org.apache.fontbox.type1.Type1Parser.readEncoding(Type1Parser.java:226)
5521    at org.apache.fontbox.type1.Type1Parser.parseASCII(Type1Parser.java:135)
5522    at org.apache.fontbox.type1.Type1Parser.parse(Type1Parser.java:61)
5523    at org.apache.fontbox.type1.Type1Font.createWithPFB(Type1Font.java:56)
5524    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FileSystemFontProvider.addType1Font(FileSystemFontProvider.java:646)
5525    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FileSystemFontProvider.scanFonts(FileSystemFontProvider.java:255)
5526    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FileSystemFontProvider.<init>(FileSystemFontProvider.java:225)
5527    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FontMapperImpl$DefaultFontProvider.<clinit>(FontMapperImpl.java:130)
5528    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FontMapperImpl.getProvider(FontMapperImpl.java:149)
5529    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FontMapperImpl.findFont(FontMapperImpl.java:413)
5530    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FontMapperImpl.findFontBoxFont(FontMapperImpl.java:376)
5531    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FontMapperImpl.getFontBoxFont(FontMapperImpl.java:350)
5532    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font.<init>(PDType1Font.java:146)
5533    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font.<clinit>(PDType1Font.java:79)
5534    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFontFactory.createFont(PDFontFactory.java:62)
5535    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDResources.getFont(PDResources.java:143)
5536    at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.operator.text.SetFontAndSize.process(SetFontAndSize.java:60)
5537    at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDFStreamEngine.processOperator(PDFStreamEngine.java:838)
5538    at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDFStreamEngine.processStreamOperators(PDFStreamEngine.java:495)
5539    at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDFStreamEngine.processStream(PDFStreamEngine.java:469)
5540    at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDFStreamEngine.processPage(PDFStreamEngine.java:150)
5541    at org.apache.pdfbox.text.LegacyPDFStreamEngine.processPage(LegacyPDFStreamEngine.java:139)
5542    at org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper.processPage(PDFTextStripper.java:391)
5543    at org.apache.tika.parser.pdf.PDF2XHTML.processPage(PDF2XHTML.java:147)
5544    at org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper.processPages(PDFTextStripper.java:319)
5545    at org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper.writeText(PDFTextStripper.java:266)
5546    at org.apache.tika.parser.pdf.PDF2XHTML.process(PDF2XHTML.java:117)
5547    at org.apache.tika.parser.pdf.PDFParser.parse(PDFParser.java:168)
5548    at org.apache.tika.parser.CompositeParser.parse(CompositeParser.java:280)
5549    at org.apache.tika.parser.CompositeParser.parse(CompositeParser.java:280)
5550    at org.apache.tika.parser.AutoDetectParser.parse(AutoDetectParser.java:143)
5551    at org.apache.tika.cli.TikaCLI$OutputType.process(TikaCLI.java:205)
5552    at org.apache.tika.cli.TikaCLI.process(TikaCLI.java:486)
5553    at org.apache.tika.cli.TikaCLI.main(TikaCLI.java:145)
```

It's one out of many others.

Here is small list:

```
ERROR Could not load font file: /home/$USER/.fonts/bakoma/pfb/eufm6.pfb
ERROR Could not load font file: /home/$USER/.fonts/bakoma/pfb/euex9.pfb
ERROR Could not load font file: /home/$USER/.fonts/bakoma/pfb/eusm10.pfb
ERROR Could not load font file: /home/$USER/.fonts/bakoma/pfb/cmmi7.pfb
ERROR Could not load font file: /home/$USER/.fonts/bakoma/pfb/msam6.pfb
```

They seem to all come from: `.fonts/bakoma/pfb/`

When I went on FireFox I saw this:

[image]

I removed the fonts from ~/.fonts/ and clear the font cache and now everything is back to normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "WARN  No Unicode mapping" messages are only relevant if you do text extraction, i.e. your text will be nothing for that glyph because the unicode mapping is missing. "TCBLZV+LCIRCLE10" indicates an **embedded** font subset, so adding fonts won't help anyway. See also this:
https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/faq.html#notext

So your real question ends there, it doesn't get better by loading fonts, unless you'd have trouble with non-embedded fonts.

The error "Found Token[kind=NAME, text=dup] but expected INTEGER" indicates an error parsing a type 1 font. This can be a syntax error in the font, or a bug in the PDFBox type 1 font parser. I rather suspect the later, because type 1 fonts are based on PostScript and the PDFBox parser can recognize only a subset of it.

Update: I looked at the eurb9.pfb font. It is like I suspected, the ASCII part of the font has a calculation ("dup dup 161 10 getinterval 0 exch putinterval dup dup 173 23 getinterval 10 exch putinterval dup dup 127 exch 196 get put readonly def") and we can't parse it. Our own type 1 parser can only parse elements that don't calculate. (This still covers 99% of type1 fonts)

Comment: And why is my Linux system screwing up the font? Is it because like PDFBox it only supports a subset of OpenType? (By the way I removed those fonts so everything is ok now. I am just curious.) Thanks for this long answer!

Comment: I am not a Linux expert so I can't answer that one, sorry.

Comment: Is there a ticket for this for the PDFBox project? (I don't know what keywords to use to search for this in the JIRA)

Comment: The "messed up firefox on linux" isn't a PDFBox problem. The type1 parsing problem is a PDFBox problem but one that can't be solved because we won't write a PostScript interpreter. If you want to use these fonts for PDF creation, use their TrueType version. The missing unicode isn't a bug, that's your PDF that doesn't have unicode mapping or a wrong mapping. This is sometimes done on purpose to prevent text extraction.

Comment: For the first part I guessed that much. Thanks for the extra information. Truly appreciated. One idea I had to change the font format to another one that PDFBox would understand (I did not make the PDF). Because since I am using Tika I am think of using Tesseract or Tensorflow to extract the elements that are not recognized.